# How to deal with populating dropdowns via a Load Saved Search function

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery, ajax

So, I have 3 dropdown boxes called marketOrg, region, and district that are filled via ajax calls. Market is filled when the page loads and then when the user selects a marketOrg from that dropdown, it calls the getRegion() javascript function. This takes the value of the marketOrg, does an ajax call on it, and populates the region dropdown. The user would then do the same operation with region to fill the district box.

How I currently have it configured is I'm emptying the region and district boxes completely whenever I switch my marketOrg. This would be completely fine, but I also have to have a function that saves the entire search (ex. User picks a marketOrg, region, and district and can save that as a special search to be loaded and populated later).

The problem with this is if I just load a full search with a marketOrg, region, or district 1 of 2 things will happen. 1. It'll see that the marketOrg changed so it'll just wipe the values in the region/district box or 2. It'll put the correct values on the boxes but if I want to change district or something, I can't because of the waterfall type of ajax loading I was doing.

Are there any sort of solutions or workarounds that anyone has found to this type of problem? Any pathways or advice would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I actually fixed this in a pretty simplistic manner. When I loaded the information from the database, before I pushed the info directly to the drops, I checked their values. I then used those values to call the ajax functions separately.